# Textview textColor to drawable produces wrong color randomly

Tags: android

I have a few textviews that has drawable selector as both background and textcolor.
I use this to invert the colors when pressed: light bg & dark text -> dark bg & light text

This has been working fine, but when I added an other textview in a activity further back in app I got a rendering issue. Now all textviews gets purple textcolor, no matter if they are pressed or not. Even if they are not on the same activity as the new textview.

This issue even persisted after removing the textview and thus reverting the code back.

This is the statelist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- pressed -->
<!-- focused -->
<!-- disabled -->
<!-- default -->

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray_background" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/grad_green_end" />
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/iconTint" />
<item android:drawable="@color/grad_green_end" />
```

and the implementation is just:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/button_green_gray_text"
```

Comment: move your `button_green_gray_text.xml` file in color folder and use it like `android:textColor="@color/button_green_gray_text"`

Comment: Actually, the issue was in the selector xml.
Changed 'android:drawable' to 'android:color' and the issue went away.

Sounds obvious, but how the heck has it been working fine up until now?